# How can I run a powershell command as admin programmatically?

Tags: windows, powershell, administrator, command-line-arguments

I want to run a powershell command as admin through programming languages as VBScript. I have seen this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51812328/11309992) but `Start-Process` only runs executable and not really a powershell command with arguments. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: [Running a command as Administrator using PowerShell? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690994/running-a-command-as-administrator-using-powershell)

Comment: @DavidPostill its the same thing, I'm trying to run a simple command `Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "Path"` using the above example and I'm getting `Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: No application is associated with the specified file for this operation.`

Comment: alr i found a self-elevated script, thanks for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Invoke-Command`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.1) with `-RunAsAdministrator`. Although, this only works with containers.

```
> Invoke-Command -RunAsAdministrator -ContainerId ... -ScriptBlock { 
    # The code you want to run
  }
```